# Getting only fully filled rows from subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, query-optimization

| id | Plot_name | Measurement | firmware_revision |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | InboundTraffic1Byte | 300 | 1.5 |
| 2 | InboundTraffic500Bytes | 200 | 1.5 |
| 3 | InboundTraffic1000Bytes | 100 | 1.5 |
| 4 | InboundTraffic1Byte |  | 1.6 |
| 5 | InboundTraffic500Bytes | 200 | 1.6 |
| 6 | InboundTraffic1000Bytes | 100 | 1.6 |

A MySQL database stores measurements from performance tests, and there is a Grafana which has some queries to get the specific data for plots. I have a single plot for inbound traffic that shows all 3 inbound measurements for 1B, 500B and 1000B for each firmware_revision. So 3 lines on the plot.

In Grafana I need to get columns with firmware_revision and each measurement type:

| firmware_revision | inbound_1B | inbound_500B | inbound_1000B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.5 | 300 | 100 | 200 |
| 1.6 |  | 200 | 100 |

I get it with this:

```
SELECT 
  firmware_revision, 
  (SELECT Measurement FROM db WHERE Plot_name like "InboundTraffic1Byte") as inbound_1B,
  (SELECT Measurement FROM db WHERE Plot_name like "InboundTraffic500Byte") as inbound_500B,
  (SELECT Measurement FROM db WHERE Plot_name like "InboundTraffic1000Byte") as inbound_1000B,
FROM 
  db
ORDER BY
  id
```

I'd like to get rid of the rows that have any of the measurements missing. So the whole row with firmware_revision 1.6 should be gone.
I add WHERE to the code above:

```
WHERE firmware_revision in (
    SELECT firmware_revision FROM db WHERE ... AND ... AND ... )
```

In the ... I have a query that checks if firmware_revision is in each of the measurements.
If any is missing, this row is skipped.

This is very slow. What is a better way of having this initial data for Grafana without using subqueries?

Comment: Using CASE EXPRESSION ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a better way of having this inital data for Grafan without
> using subqueries

You can do it using CASE EXPRESSION, which is faster than Subqueries :

```
SELECT 
  firmware_revision, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN Plot_name = 'InboundTraffic1Byte' THEN Measurement END) as inbound_1B,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Plot_name = 'InboundTraffic500Byte' THEN Measurement END) as inbound_500B,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Plot_name = 'InboundTraffic1000Byte' THEN Measurement END) as inbound_1000B
FROM 
  db
GROUP BY
  firmware_revision
HAVING 
  inbound_1B IS NOT NULL AND inbound_500B IS NOT NULL AND inbound_1000B IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems like MAX + CASE was exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Well,
You would also use `SUM()` expression on the same lines;

Like;
`SUM(CASE WHEN Plot_name = 'InboundTraffic1Byte' THEN Measurement ELSE 0 END) as inbound_1B,`                       `........and so on`

Answer (score 0):

Slight alternative approach is to

- first filter out records that are not null
- apply the pivot (`MAX` + `CASE` expressions)
- check when the count of records is 3

```
SELECT firmware_revision,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Plot_name REGEXP '.*1Byte$'    
                THEN Measurement END) AS inbound_1B,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Plot_name REGEXP '.*500Bytes$'  
                THEN Measurement END) AS inbound_500B,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Plot_name REGEXP '.*1000Bytes$' 
                THEN Measurement END) AS inbound_1000B
FROM tab       
WHERE Measurement IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY firmware_revision
HAVING COUNT(id) = 3
```

**Output**:

| firmware_revision | inbound_1B | inbound_500B | inbound_1000B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.5 | 300 | 200 | 100 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bCXBMEYT1q54dKwReRXPui/2).

Comment: Thank you! I checked solution with max+case and it works perfectly :)